# How to log Character decoding error in Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, logging

In my Servlet I am receiving a GET request with a parameter. I am then trying to decode the parameter and log possible encoding errors:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String json = req.getParameter("json");

    try{
        String jsonDecoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(json, "UTF-8");
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalArgumentException e){
        // log error somewhere
    }
}
```

Problem is, the try/catch part of the code is useless, since the parameter is already processed from the getParameter function, and the string arriving at line 5 is already decoded. If I call the servlet with an invalid parameter, I get the error logged in catalina.out, and the variable has a null value:

```
Aug 17, 2015 11:22:07 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
INFO: Character decoding failed. Parameter [json] with value [...] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
 Note: further occurrences of Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

What I want instead is to log the error to my own log (e.g. handle it with log4j). Is it possible to redirect that line of log from catalina.out to my own logger (Please note I do not want to log ALL from the catalina.out file)? As an alternative, is it possible to get the unprocessed parameter from the HttpServletRequest, and then process it as I like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [getQueryString](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) method since you want to decode the value yourself. It returns -

> a String containing the query string or null if the URL contains no query string. The value is not decoded by the container.

Something like below should do it

```
String queryStr = URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was getting to the same conclusion. Thank you!!